# ANTLR4: Reference book examples static class definitions

Tags: java

In alot of the example in the book specifically in chapter 7 there are a bunch of tree walker and listeners which are defined by using this definition:

```
public static class PropertyFileLoader extends PropretyFileBaseListener{
...
public static class PropertyFileVisitor extends PropertyFileBaseVisitor<Void>
...
```

Why is the static there? What does it do?

The link above is talking about nested inner classes, I don't have any nested inner classes... I cant see a difference on using the static keyword and not using the static keyword.

An example of the auto generated classes produced by antlr are as follows:

```
public class CymbolBaseListener implements CymbolListener {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
        @Override public void enterVarDecl(CymbolParser.VarDeclContext ctx){ }


public interface CymbolListener extends ParseTreeListener {
    /**
     * Enter a parse tree produced by {@link CymbolParser#rules}.
     * @param ctx the parse tree
     */
    void enterVarDecl(CymbolParser.VarDeclContext ctx);
```

where ParseTreeListener comes with the antlr runtime [ParseTreeListener](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/index.html?org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeListener.html)

If I wanted to use that these classes what I would do is the following:

```
public class MyListener extends CymbolBaseListener {
    public void enterVarDecl(CymbolParser.VarDeclContext ctx)
    {
        System.out.println("I have found a variable declaration!");
    }
}
```

and the way to get the listener going would be to write a static main which does the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ANTLRFileStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]);
    CymbolLexer mylexer = new CymbolLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(mylexer);
    CymbolParser myparser = new CymbolParser(tokens);
    MyListener listener = new MyListener();
    ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
    ParseTree tree = myparser.rules();
    walker.walk(listener, tree);
}
```

Why has the author made most of the examples use the static keyword:

```
public static class MyListener extends CymbolBaseListener
```

as a non-static class could also be used.
I have just realized that some examples in the book have the static keyword whereas others do not but I don't understand what the intention behind it is.

Comment: Is it about the "static" keyword, or is why the design of those classes includes "static" property?

Comment: Yes, why design those classes with the static property? As I usually dont include the static when I use the antlr generated visitors

Comment: Then you should say that it is not a duplicate. Raise this to the moderators.
Also it cannot be answered without having the code. We need more information to understand the design decision. Otherwise people will start guessing.